# Java - Check for x alike integers in a list of integers

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, integer

I'd like to go through a list of integers and make action if I find 6 integers that are alike, or another if there is 5 alike, or another if there is 4 alike etc...How can I do this. I have the method:

```
public int calculatePoints(ArrayList<Integer> dice) {
    //Check for 6 alike
    //if not, check for 5 alike
    //if not, check for 4 alike
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically are you stuck on?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I can't think of a solution to the problem. The list-argument can have any given number of elements, and I don't know how to run through it to check if there is x number of integers that are the same.

Comment: I thought of adding a for loop going through all elements in the argument list:

for(Integer num : dice) {

}

Could possible create a Map, seeing this is for checking how many of the similar dice that are in the list. Map<Integer,Integer> being Map<whatDice,AmountOfTHatDice>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it: (*Assuming you only want to check against the number that occurs the most*)

```
public static int calculatePoints(ArrayList<Integer> dice) {
        int max = 0;
        for(Integer die : dice) {
            int temp = Collections.frequency(dice, die);
            if(temp > max) {
                max = temp;
            }
        }
        if(max >= 6) {
            //Do stuff
        } else if (max >=5) {
            //Do stuff
        } else if (max >= 4) {
            //Do stuff
        }        
        return 0;
    }
```

Basic logic:

-Go through every `Integer` in the array and use the [frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) method to see how many times it occurred. If it is more than the max, then resolve the number to `max`. Then at the end, it `if-else` statements to check how many times the number occurred and do what you want inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Please check out the answer that I posted

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not have the reputation enough to edit my post, here is my answer @GBlodgett:

Hey! thanks for the reply. I am in the process of making a game of Farkle, therefore I need to find out how many 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s, 5s, and 6s that are in the list and then give points thereafter(following the rules). I made a code that seems to work, allthough there has got to be a more effective way to do it. Feel free to take a look and give me some feedback:

public int calculatePoints(ArrayList dice) {

```
    int points = 0;
    Map<Integer,Integer> numOfDice = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    numOfDice.put(1, 0);
    numOfDice.put(2, 0);
    numOfDice.put(3, 0);
    numOfDice.put(4, 0);
    numOfDice.put(5, 0);
    numOfDice.put(6, 0);

    for(Integer num : dice) {
        if(numOfDice.get(num) == null) {
            numOfDice.put(num, 1);
        }
        else {
        numOfDice.put(num, numOfDice.get(num)+1);
        }
    }
    for(int i=1; i <= numOfDice.size(); i++) {
        if(i == 1) {
            if(numOfDice.get(1) < 3) {
                points += numOfDice.get(1)*100;
            }
            else if(numOfDice.get(1) == 3) {
                points += 1000;
            }
            else if(numOfDice.get(1) == 4) {
                points += 2000;
            }
            else if(numOfDice.get(1) == 5) {
                points += 3000;
            }
            else if(numOfDice.get(1) == 6) {
                points += 5000;
            }
        }
        else {

        if(i == 5) {
            if(numOfDice.get(5) < 3) {
                points += 50*numOfDice.get(5);
                continue;
            }
        }
        //All else
        if(numOfDice.get(i) == 3) {
            points += 100*i;
        }
        else if(numOfDice.get(i) == 4) {
            points += 200*i;
        }
        else if(numOfDice.get(i) == 5) {
            points += 300*i;
        }
        else if(numOfDice.get(i) == 6) {
            points += 400*i;
        }
    }
}
    return points;
```

}